# Is a bit field any more efficient (computationally) than masking bits and extracting the data by hand?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have a numerous small pieces of data that I want to be able to shove into one larger data type. Let's say that, hypothetically, this is a date and time. The obvious method is via a bit field like this.

```
struct dt
{
    unsigned long minute :6;
    unsigned long hour :5;
    unsigned long day :5;
    unsigned long month :4;
    unsigned long year :12;
}stamp;
```

Now let's pretend that this thing is ordered so that things declared first are at bits of higher significance than things declared later so if I represent the bits by the first letter of the variable it would look like:

```
mmmmmm|hhhhh|ddddd|mmmm|yyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Finally, let's pretend that I simply declare an unsigned long and split it up using masks and shifts to do the same things.

```
unsigned long dateTime;
```

Here is my question:
Are the following to methods of accessing minutes, hours, etc. equivalent in terms of what the computer needs to do? Or is there some tricksy method that the compiler/computer uses with the bit fields.

```
unsigned minutes = stamp.minutes;
//versus
unsigned minutes = ((dateTime & 0xf8000000)>>26;
```

and

```
unsigned hours = stamp.hours;
//versus
unsigned hours = ((dateTime & 0x07C00000)>>21;
```

etc.

Comment: I would put the years in the high bits month next etc. Then when you want to compare the objects you do not need to extract the year to get them in order the normal < operator on the integer will work.

Comment: That's a pretty clever trick, I will have to remember it in the futre. Unfortunately I am not storing dates and times in the program I am writing. In my code it is being used to store gamma ray energy, detector number, and a detector efficiency correction value (so it doesn't have to be recomputed from a complex little bastard of a formula every time I need it.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler generates the same instructions that you would explicitly write to access the bits. So don't expect it to be faster with bitfields.

In fact, strictly speaking with bitfields you don't control how they are positioned in the word of data (unless your compiler gives you some additional guarantees. I mean that the C99 standard doesn't define any). Doing masks by hand, you can at least place the two most often accessed fields first and last in the series, because in these two positions, it takes one operation instead of two to isolate the field.

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out why something in the most significant bits would be faster; but, it is because you only need to shift down rather than bitwise and then shift, do I have that right?

Comment: @James Exactly. That was only for reading though. I realized that for changing one of the fields (leaving the others the same), if you ever have to do that, only the least-significant field has an advantage.

Comment: "The compiler generates the same instructions that you would explicitly write to access the bits. So don't expect it to be faster with bitfields." -- this isn't always true. Some CPUs have instructions exactly for this, manipulation with bitfields, MC68020+ comes into my mind. They are not always fastest solution but in some cases they are.

Comment: @Miro: In this case, any decent compiler would use those instructions for your hand-written code to access particular bits...

Answer (score 7):

Those will probably compile the the same machine code, but if it really matters, benchmark it. Or, better yet, just use the bitfield because it's easier!

Quickly testing gcc yields:

```
shrq    $6, %rdi             ; using bit field
movl    %edi, %eax
andl    $31, %eax
```

vs.

```
andl    $130023424, %edi     ; by-hand
shrl    $21, %edi
movl    %edi, %eax
```

This is a little-endian machine, so the numbers are different, but the three instructions are nearly same.

Comment: The bitfield version is slightly better as it uses smaller constants (1-byte instead of 4-byte), which makes the code slightly smaller, saving on icache space/impact

Comment: @Chris Dodd: True, but I think that's because gcc arranged the fields differently...

Comment: @Chris Dodd: Then perhaps the constants can be reduced by allocating an array of characters and sneakily casting things? For instance if I had an 11 bit number then a 7 bit number and then a 14 bit number I could do something like: char numbers[4]; first=((reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(number)&0xffe0)>>5); second=((reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(number+1)&0x1fc0)>>6); third=(reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(number+2)&0x03ff);

Comment: forget the above comment, I just realized that assignments in both directions are dangerously dependent on whether the machine is big endian or little endian.

Answer (score 5):

It is entirely platform and compiler dependent. Some processors, especially microcontrollers, have bit addressing instructions or bit addressable memory, and the compiler can use these directly if you use built-in language constructs. If you use bit-masking to operate on bits on such a processor, the compiler will have to be smarter to spot the potential optimisation.

On most desktop platforms I would suggest that you are sweating the small stuff, but if you need to know, you should test it by profiling or timing the code, or analyse the generated code. Note that you may get very different results depending on compiler optimisation options, and even different compilers.

Answer (score 4):

In this examle I would use the bit field manually.
But **not** because of accesses. But because of the ability to compare two dt's.
In the end the compiler will always generate better code than you (as the compiler will get better over time and never make mistakes) but this code is simple enough that you will probably write optimum code (but this is the kind of micro optimization you should not be worrying about).

If your dt is an integer formatted as:

```
yyyyyyyyyyyy|mmmm|ddddd|hhhhh|mmmmmm
```

Then you can naturally compare them like this.

```
dt t1(getTimeStamp());
dt t2(getTimeStamp());

if (t1 < t2)
{    std::cout << "T1 happened before T2\n";
}
```

By using a bit field structure the code looks like this:

```
dt t1(getTimeStamp());
dt t2(getTimeStamp());

if (convertToInt(t1) < convertToInt(t2))
{    std::cout << "T1 happened before T2\n";
}
// or
if ((t1.year < t2.year)
    || ((t1.year == t2.year) && ((t1.month < t2.month)
      || ((t1.month == t2.month) && ((t1.day < t2.day)
        || ((t1.day == t2.day) && (t1.hour  etc.....
```

Of course you could get the best of both worlds by using a union that has the structure on one side and the int as the alternative. Obviously this will depend exactly on how your compiler works and you will need to test that the objects are getting placed in the correct positions (but this would be perfect place to learn about TDD.

Comment: -1 for several reasons.  It is not true that a compiler will always generate better code than a human.  Compilers don't get better over time. 
Even the smallest optimizations can matter in some circumstances, particularly in embedded code.  Its a bad practice to have your code depend on exactly how your compiler works, particularly when you had to test it to see how it works.

Comment: @jeanne: 1) As the compiler never makes mistakes I find that is more important than any micro optimization a human can make.

Comment: @jeanne: 2) Every time a human actually figures out a macro optimization. It will be included in the next version of the compiler. So yes compilers do get better over time.

Comment: @jeanne: 3) Yes. Your code should never depend on compiler dependencies. And my suggestion does not. But it would be nice for a new user to test it so that he understands why!

Comment: @jeanne: 4) TDD is a pretty standard way of developing good robust code. Suggesting it is bad idea to test is just silly even if you are sure it is correct testing is always a god idea.

Answer (score 1):

Only if your architecture explicitly has a set of instructions for bit-wise manipulation and access.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you use bit fields, then you let the compiler worry about how to store the data (bitfields are pretty much completely implementation-defined), which means that:

- It might use more space than necessary, and
- Accessing each member will be done efficiently.

The compiler will typically organize the layout of the struct so that the second assumption holds, at the cost of total size of the struct.

The compiler will probably insert padding between each member, to ease access to each field.

On the other hand, if you just store everything in a single `unsigned long` (or an array of chars), then it's up to you to implement efficient access, but you have a guarantee of the layout. It will take up a fixed size, and there will be no padding. And that means that copying the value around may get less expensive. And it'll be more portable (assuming you use a fixed-size int type instead of just `unsigned int`).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can sometimes combine the access to the bitfields in a non intuitive matter. I once disassembled the code generated (gcc 3.4.6 for sparc) when accessing 1 bit entries that where used in a conditionnal expressions. The compiler fused the access to the bits and made the comparison with integers. I will try to reproduce the idea (not at work and can not access the source code that was involved):

```
struct bits {
  int b1:1;
  int b2:1;
  int b3:1;
  ...
} x;

if(x.b1 && x.b2 && !x.b3)
...
if(x.b2 && !x.b2 && x.b3)
```

was compiled to something equivalent to (I know the bitorder in my example is the opposite but it is only for the sake of simplification of the example).

```
temp = (x & 7);
if( temp == 6)
...
if( temp == 5)
```

There's also another point to consider if one wants to use bitfields (they are often more readable than bit-kungfu), if you have some bits to spare, it can be useful to reserve whole bytes for certain fields, thus simplifying access by the processor.
An 8 bits field that is aligned can be loaded with a move byte command and doesn't need the masking step.

Comment: yea and when folks do bit-kungfu it is much more maintainable to use #define for bit positions and/or masks that reminds others or your future self what you did.  if you need to do it in more than one place macros for the mask creation from bit position and width is helpful.  e.g. `#define extractBitField(value, lsb, width) ((value >> lsb) & ((1 << width) -1))`